# Is there any scalene non right angled triangle having its sides as simple rational numbers and whose angles have very simple trigonometric ratios?

Tags: trigonometry, contest-math, triangles

I am currently learning conditional trigonometric identities such as $ \sin{2A} + \sin{2B} +\sin{2C} = 4\sin{A}\sin{B}\sin{C}$  for $A + B+C = \pi$,  that is they are angles in a triangle.

I am preparing for a multiple choice exam where time per question is only about $2$ minutes. Such identities are often asked in the form where **LHS** is given as the given and one is asked to chose the correct option for the **RHS** expression. It is very time consuming to actually prove the identity and then chose the correct option.

Hence there is often a short cut to such problems wherein one can check all four options by substituting ratios of some common *simple* triangle such as the $30-60-90$ triangle. This works most of the times.

However sometimes it so happens that two options seem to be correct when we check using the $30-60-90$ triangle but in reality only one answer is correct. This happens because I am using a special type of triangle (right triangle).

**To avoid this I am looking for a general triangle (scalene and non right angled) with simple rational sides (like $2$ or $\frac{3}{4}$) as well as angles whose trigonometric ratios are *simple* enough so that my method is feasible.**

Comment: By the Law of Cosines, any integer-sided triangle has angles whose cosines are rational. To get rational sines, you only need to ensure rational area (by the area formula $\frac12 a b \sin C$). One way to do this is to take two integer-sided right triangles with a common leg, and glue them together along that leg. For instance, $9$-$12$-$15$ and $5$-$12$-$13$ make a $13$-$14$-$15$ triangle. The trig ratios for two of the angles can be read immediately from the right-triangular pieces; area is easy, too. Finding the trigs of the third angle takes only a little effort.

Comment: Can you make this into a answer @Blue ?

Answer (score 2):

By the Law of Cosines, any integer-sided triangle has angles whose cosines are rational. To get rational sines, you only need to ensure rational area (by the area formula $\frac12 a b \sin C$).

One way to do this is to take two integer-sided right triangles with a common leg, and glue them together along that leg. For instance, a $9$-$12$-$15$ and a $5$-$12$-$13$ make a $13$-$14$-$15$ triangle.

[image]

The trig ratios for two of the angles can be read immediately from the right-triangular pieces; area is easy, too. Finding the trigs of the third angle takes only a little effort. For the $13$-$14$-$15$ triangle above, we have
$$\sin A = \frac{4}{5} \qquad \cos A = \frac{3}{5} \qquad \sin B = \frac{12}{13} \qquad \cos B = \frac{5}{13} \qquad \text{area} = 84$$
$$\sin C = \frac{2\cdot 84}{15\cdot 13} = \frac{56}{65} \qquad \cos C = \frac{-14^2+15^2+13^2}{2\cdot 15\cdot 13} = \frac{33}{65}$$

These aren't necessarily the "simplest" ratios, I suppose, but they're a place to start.

If, more generally, you attach a $p$-$q$-$r$ right triangle to an $s$-$q$-$t$ right triangle ...

[image]

... then you get ...

$$\sin A = \frac{q}{r} \qquad \cos A = \frac{p}{r} \qquad \sin B = \frac{q}{t} \qquad \cos B = \frac{s}{t} \qquad \text{area} = \frac12(p+s)q$$
$$\sin C = \frac{(p+s)q}{rt} \qquad \cos C = \frac{q^2-ps}{rt}$$

Experimenting with values here could generate some simpler ratios.

You mention having used $30^\circ$-$60^\circ$-$90^\circ$ triangles, which suggests a certain tolerance for irrationals and, therefore, a certain flexibility with the above. For instance, you could take $q := \sqrt{n}$ (and all other sides integer); granted, all the sines become irrational, but at least they *match*, in that they are all rational multiples of $\sqrt{n}$. The cosines remain rational. Something to consider.